# child/parent problem rendering simple bar chart in react,

Tags: reactjs, charts, bar-chart, recharts

"EDITED"
I'm trying to make a very minimalist bar chart.
It doesn't, render. It seems that the child component isn't rendering after the parent component's state has changed.

for example. if I make a change in my code in the MiniChart component, and save the changed through my IDE. the charts will render correctly. but as soon as navigate to another page in my app through my browser and come back to where the charts are, then they won't render.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Child component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {BarChart, Bar} from 'recharts';
  

const MiniChart = (props) => {
    
    
    const [apiUrl] = useState("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/"+props.id+"/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=30&interval=daily");
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState([]);
    const [r, setR] = useState([]);
    
// fetch data from api
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        if(parseInt(props.rank) < 5){   
            const result = await axios(apiUrl,);
            setData(result.data.prices);
        } else {setMsg("TEST : not loaded");}
    }
    setR(data.map(elem => ({ 'val': elem[1]}))); 
    fetchData();
    
    return()=>{
    }
}, [apiUrl, props.rank]);



    return (
        <div>
            <BarChart width={150} height={40} data={r}>
                <Bar dataKey='val' fill="green" />
            </BarChart>
        </div>
    )

}
export default MiniChart
```

Parent component:

```
import React, { useState} from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faStar } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import MiniChart from './MiniChart';




const Crypto = (props) => {

    const location = useLocation();
    const [starColor, setStarColor] = useState(props.defaultStarCol);
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    const getFavs = cookies.getAll();
   

    // toggle color, re-render, remove or add to cookies
    const handleFavToggle = (e) => {
        if(starColor === '#ebc934'){
            setStarColor('lightgrey');
            cookies.remove(props.id, props.id, { path: '/' });
            if(location.pathname === '/favorites'){
                function refreshPage() {
                    window.location.reload(false);
                  }
                refreshPage();
            }  
        } else {
            setStarColor('#ebc934');
            cookies.set(props.id, props.id, { path: '/' });
            //console.log(cookies.getAll());
        }
    }


        return (
            <div>
                <li>
                    <div className="lidiv">
                        {props.id in getFavs? //ADD IF LOGGED IN !
                         <p className="pml"><FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:'#ebc934'}} onClick={handleFavToggle} className="star" icon={faStar}/></p>
                         : <p className="pml"><FontAwesomeIcon style={{color:'lightgrey'}} onClick={handleFavToggle} className="star" icon={faStar}/></p>}
                        
                        <p className="pml">{props.rank}</p>
                        <img className="iconimg" src={props.img} alt=""/>
                        <p className="pxl coinName"><Link to="/crypto" style={{display: 'block'}}>{props.coin}</Link></p>
                        <p className="pml">{props.tag}</p>
                        <p className="pml4">{props.price}</p>
                        <p className="pml" style={{color: (props.oneday).charAt(0)==='-' ? 'red': 'green'}}>{props.oneday}%</p>
                        <p className="pxl daycash" style={{color: (props.oneday).charAt(0)==='-' ? 'red': 'green'}}>{props.onedaycurr} </p>
                        <p className="pxl-4">{props.mcap}M</p>
                        <MiniChart className="pxl" id={props.id} rank={props.rank}></MiniChart>
                          
                    </div>
                </li>
            </div>
        )
}
export default Crypto;
```

Comment: create a local state for data as well.

Comment: I put : const [pd2, setPd2] = useState([]); instead of : var pd2 = []; the result remains the same :(

Comment: how did you set the data while using the local state?

Comment: And you can try with the hardcoded value before integrating with API

Comment: After trying with hard coded data I figured out that the problem isn't coming from the data. in fact I noticed that when I save the changed within my IDE and the charts will show in my browser window. but when I reload the page on my browser, or if I switch to another page in my app and then come back the the one where the chart is supposed to show , it won't show anymore.